# Specify default build tools on project creation

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm just starting with Android development and I'm having problem starting my first project. In SDK manager I downloaded SDK platform with API level 24, and in SDK tools I downloaded all 24.0.x versions. When I try to set up new project and select target api version 24 android studio proceeds to download build tools version 26.0.2.
Can I somehow specify which version of build tools I want on project creation?

[SDK platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1dFe.png)

[Build tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN5CO.png)

[Api target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlCtr.png)

[Android studio starts the download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhYor.png)

Comment: why would you not want the latest build tools?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I understand what you mean but I would like to have an option. Now I downloaded 26.0.3 and now it asks to download SDK platform 26. Why we even have an option to download multiple if it forces us to use latest?

Comment: you can just change it in the gradle file, you're not forced to use anything

Comment: @TimCastelijns Unless there is some option hidden somewhere, until I download version 26 and finish creating project (to be able to access gradle file) I cant change it. So I am forced to download it.

Comment: @TimCastelijns and now after I downloaded sdk platform 26 i get error asking for build tools 26.0.2 even tho I have 26.0.3.